# One liner to restructure/nest a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wondering if in Python3 there is a one liner that can turn:

```py
in_dict = {
    ("ID1", "TEXT_A"): "TIMESTAMP_X",
    ("ID1", "TEXT_B"): "TIMESTAMP_Y",
    ("ID2", "TEXT_C"): "TIMESTAMP_X",
    ("ID3", "TEXT_E"): "TIMESTAMP_Y",
}
```

into

```py
out_dict = {
    "ID1": [
        {"TEXT_A": "TIMESTAMP_X"}, 
        {"TEXT_B": "TIMESTAMP_Y"}
    ],
    "ID2": [{"TEXT_C": "TIMESTAMP_X"}],
    "ID3": [{"TEXT_E": "TIMESTAMP_Y"}],
}
```

I know I can easily do this in a for loop but I was wondering if there is a super fancy way.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is using `groupby` if keys of dictionary are in sorted manner as in your case

```
from itertools import groupby
in_dict = {
    ("ID1", "TEXT_A"): "TIMESTAMP_X",
    ("ID1", "TEXT_B"): "TIMESTAMP_Y",
    ("ID2", "TEXT_C"): "TIMESTAMP_X",
    ("ID3", "TEXT_E"): "TIMESTAMP_Y",
}
print({k : [{y[1]: in_dict[y]} for y in v]  for k,v in groupby(in_dict, key=lambda x: x[0])})
 # output
 {'ID1': [{'TEXT_A': 'TIMESTAMP_X'}, {'TEXT_B': 'TIMESTAMP_Y'}],
 'ID2': [{'TEXT_C': 'TIMESTAMP_X'}],
 'ID3': [{'TEXT_E': 'TIMESTAMP_Y'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way,

```py
{ uniq_k : [ {k[1] : v } for k, v in in_dict.items() if uniq_k in k ] for uniq_k in {k[0] for k in in_dict} }
```

Answer (score 0):

For abusing Python, `functools.reduce()` is often more helpful than mere loops.

Like when mentioning a for loop, you may mean something like

```
out_dict={}
for k in in_dict:
  if k[0] not in out_dict:
    out_dict[k[0]]=[]
  out_dict[k[0]].append({k[1]:in_dict[k]})
```

which could be rewritten as

```
from functools import reduce
def rf(acc,k):
  if k[0] not in acc:
    acc[k[0]]=[]
  acc[k[0]].append({k[1]:in_dict[k]})
  return acc
out_dict=reduce(rf,in_dict,{})
```

and then `rf()` can be tricked into a lambda:

```
from functools import reduce
out_dict=reduce(lambda acc,k:[acc.update({k[0]:[]}) if k[0] not in acc else None,acc[k[0]].append({k[1]:in_dict[k]}),acc][2],in_dict,{})
```

while the `else None` is particularly repelling, replacing it with something meaningful actually makes the thing longer, even after swapping order to get rid of the `not`:

```
out_dict=reduce(lambda acc,k:[acc[k[0]].append({k[1]:in_dict[k]}) if k[0] in acc else acc.update({k[0]:[{k[1]:in_dict[k]}]}),acc][1],in_dict,{})
```